# Spring security 3, infinite loop at login

Tags: xml, security, spring, spring-security

Here is my security-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <sec:http entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" filters="none"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/showlogin.wss*" filters="none" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <sec:anonymous/>
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="authEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/showlogin.wss" />
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="steve" password="foo" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <sec:user name="admin" password="bar" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

As you can see there is no filters applied to the login page (showlogin.wss) but still, I'm getting in an infinite loop while trying to access the page, can someone tell me why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does removing the `*` after `.wss` below make any difference?

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/showlogin.wss*" filters="none" />
```